# Browsing while there is a web server connected to same router

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, webserver

I'm trying to set up my own Nextcloud server on PC with Ubuntu 18.04 in my home network. I want it to be accessible from Internet so I forwarded ports 80 and 443. But after I did it I couldn't browse Internet from all other devices. As far as I know this is to be expected since all websites data goes to web server.
Is it possible to 
1) be able to access my server from Internet
2) access websites from other devices connected to the same network
at the same time? 
How do I do it?
Do I have to pay for another connection to my ISP to get this to work?

Comment: Forwarding would only affect traffic destined for your router, not for any other website on the Internet. Are you sure you didn't do anything else to the configuration?

Comment: This is not expected. How did you do the port forwarding?

Comment: @harrymc
My router is Mikrotik hap lite. I used
`/ip firewall nat add chain=dstnat dst-port=443 action=dst-nat protocol=tcp to-address=192.168.88.100 to-port=443`
to forward port 443 and 
`/ip firewall nat add chain=dstnat dst-port=80 action=dst-nat protocol=tcp to-address=192.168.88.100 to-port=80`
to forward port 80